# Truffle and Ganache-cli test case fails

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js, truffle, ganache

So I have this setup : `truffle` and `ganache-cli`

I'm sending some ether to my contract, here is the related part of my contract:

```
    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    function () payable public {
              uint amount = msg.value;
              balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;
        }
```

In truffle this is how I send the ether.

```
it("Test if can be payed", function(){
    return web3.eth.sendTransaction({
           from:fromAddr, 
           to:MyContract.address,  
           value:amountToSend
    }).then(function(res){  
           expect(res).to.not.be.an("error"); // test passed
    });
 });

it("Test if contract received ether", function(){
        return web3.eth.getBalance(MyContract.address, 
               function(err, res){
                        expect(parseInt(res)).to.be.at.least(1000000000000000000); // test passed
                });
});

it("Catch if balanceOf "+fromAddr, function(){
        return sale.balanceOf.call(fromAddr).then(function(res){
                        expect(parseInt(res)).to.be.at.least(1); // fails the test
               });
});
```

Am I doing it right? What could be the reason for failed test?
truffle test output :

```
AssertionError: expected 0 to be at least 1
      + expected - actual

      -0
      +1
```

I can provide more info if needed.

UPDATE : 
for clarification on `sale` which is global variable.

```
   it("Test if MyContract is deployed", function(){
            return MyContract.deployed().then(function(instance){
                   sale = instance;
            });
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

File path:
*test/vault.js*

```
const Vault = artifacts.require("Vault");

contract("Vault test", async accounts => {
    
    // Rely on one instance for all tests.
    let vault;
    let fromAccount   = accounts[0];
    let oneEtherInWei = web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether');

    // Runs before all tests.
    // https://mochajs.org/#hooks
    before(async () => {
        vault = await Vault.deployed();
    });

    // The `receipt` will return boolean.
    // https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#gettransactionreceipt
    it("Test if 1 ether can be paid", async () => {
        let receipt = await web3.eth.sendTransaction({
            from:  fromAccount, 
            to:    vault.address, 
            value: oneEtherInWei
        });
        expect(receipt.status).to.equal(true);
    });

    it("Test if contract received 1 ether", async () => {
        let balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(vault.address);
        expect(balance).to.equal(oneEtherInWei);
    });

    // In Web3JS v1.0, `fromWei` will return string.
    // In order to use `at.least`, string needs to be parsed to integer.
    it("Test if balanceOf fromAccount is at least 1 ether in the contract", async () => {
        let balanceOf    = await vault.balanceOf.call(fromAccount);
        let balanceOfInt = parseInt(web3.utils.fromWei(balanceOf, 'ether'));
        expect(balanceOfInt).to.be.at.least(1);
    });
});
```

You can see the full project [here](https://gitlab.com/zulhfreelancer/ether_transfer_truffle_tests/). Do note that I'm using [Truffle v5](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/releases/tag/v5.0.0) and [Ganache v2](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/releases/tag/v2.0.0-beta.1). See the README  file inside that GitLab repository.

Back to your question, there were 2 mistakes:

1. The `sale` is not defined. I have a feeling that you were actually referring to `MyContract`.
2. In order to use the [least](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_least) method in ChaiJS, you need to make sure you are passing integers. The `balanceOf` call is returning `BigNumber` or `BN` object and you can't use it with `.least` method.

FYI, Truffle v5 is now using `BN` by default (previously `BigNumber`). More about it [here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/releases/tag/v5.0.0#user-content-breaking-changes-truffle).

Comment: I've added some code to clarify about `sale`.
and about point #2 is my way of `parseInt(res)` not correct ?
I also have question, is using `async/await` if more preferred than using `.then' ?

Comment: I've tried following your answer, but exactly same fails appear, as per your answer 
This will pass : `it("Test if contract received 1 ether", async () => {`
This will fail : `it("Test if balanceOf fromAccount is at least 1 ether in the contract", async () => {`

Comment: `async/await` is cleaner and will make your code neat. Try to use environment like me and see if it works. Check the README file inside the repo.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will work over weekend and see.